# SBT how to use classes from Build.sbt inside plugin Task execution

Tags: scala, sbt, classloader

Any classes defined in `project/*.scala` files are made available for use by SBT inside the build definition code.

I would like those classes to be available during the execution of an SBT plugin task, but they do not appear to be available.

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

The specific problem I am trying to solve is adding custom rules for `Scalastyle`. The project [does not currently support writing your own rules](https://github.com/scalastyle/scalastyle/issues/25), but I thought I might be able to add a rule to the `project/*.sbt` files and then use it inside `Scalastyle`.

If I define a rule in `project/MyRule.scala`, then it is available in the `project/Build.scala` settings:

```
object MyBuild extends Build {

  lazy val project = Project("MyProject", file("."))
    .settings(ScalastylePlugin.Settings: _*)

  // my rule is available in this classloader:
  val test = classOf[MyRule].getName

  ...
}
```

... but when the ScalastylePlugin Task runs, the classloader it is using cannot see that class:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyRule
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
org.scalastyle.Checker$.newInstance(Checker.scala:194)
org.scalastyle.Checker$$anonfun$verifySource0$1.apply(Checker.scala:116)
org.scalastyle.Checker$$anonfun$verifySource0$1.apply(Checker.scala:116)
...
org.scalastyle.ScalastyleChecker.checkFiles(Checker.scala:64)
org.scalastyle.sbt.Tasks$.runScalastyle(Plugin.scala:121)
org.scalastyle.sbt.Tasks$.doScalastyle(Plugin.scala:90)
org.scalastyle.sbt.ScalastylePlugin$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Plugin.scala:63)
org.scalastyle.sbt.ScalastylePlugin$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Plugin.scala:63)
scala.Function6$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function6.scala:35)
scala.Function6$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function6.scala:34)
scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
...
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I have inspected the classloader in use during the `Scalastyle` task, and it has all the SBT librarydependency jars on its classpath, but no classes from the SBT project.

How can I add these classes to its classpath?

Comment: Is this full `project/Build.scala` code? I think it should be surrounded by `object MyBuild extends Build { ... }`. See [sbt docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html#relating-build-sbt-to-build-scala)

Comment: Yes, it is. I've clarified the excerpt above

Comment: I'm tempted to close it as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23409993/1305344. See my answer - section "Separation of concerns (aka @joescii in da haus)". Am I wrong to call  it a duplicate?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: This is a little different to that question, in that it's asking about making classes from the `project/` meta-project available to the plugins when building the main project. The linked question is asking about using project classes in the meta-project. They are related though.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Would you be able to publish a project on GitHub to work on the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, as [documented in the SBT documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Plugins.html#by-description)

> Note: At runtime, all plugins for all builds are loaded in a separate,
> parent class loader of the class loaders for builds. This means that
> plugins will not see classes or resources from build definitions.

#### Edited

Based on the comments, I think maybe this solution may work. In the `project/` create extra project called `scala-style-defs`. There place your rules. In the same project create `build.sbt` with the build definition e.g.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalastyle" %% "scalastyle" % "0.4.0"

resolvers += "sonatype-releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
```

Then in the `project/` create build.sbt with following content

```
lazy val root = project.in(file(".")) dependsOn(scalastyleDefs)

lazy val scalastyleDefs = Project(id="scalastyleDefs", base=file("scala-style-defs"))
```

and of course `plugins.sbt` with

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scalastyle" %% "scalastyle-sbt-plugin" % "0.4.0")

resolvers += "sonatype-releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
```

Now in your main project create `build.sbt` and there include scalastyle settings

```
org.scalastyle.sbt.ScalastylePlugin.Settings
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains why my naive implementation didn't work. Can you see a way of making classes available to plugins? What if I put them in the meta-meta-project (`project/project/`), for use by plugins in the meta-project (`project/`)?

Comment: Couldn't the plugin get a hold of the class loader for the build definition, and then access things in it via reflection?

Comment: @SethTisue and Rich please see my update. Maybe this solution will suit you. If you have problems implementing it, see my sample project https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/279703/q-22372717.tar.gz if you have any problems

Comment: @SethTisue and Rich have you tested my solution, does it suit you, do you have more questions?

Comment: @SethTisue There's actually classloader isolation between a project and the build, so you'd actually need to be super clever about how you load the classes so the scalastyle ones are the same.  THis is "dark territory" for any JVM developer.  The solution posted is  agreat compromise.

Comment: Hello there. 8 years later I respawn that question. I do have similar question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73307923/sbt-in-project-plugin-how-to-structure-them . Did you find a working solution that may still be applicable today?