# Defining sbt task that invokes method from project code?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using SBT to build a scala project. I want to define a very simple task, that when I input `generate` in sbt:

```
sbt> generate
```

It will invoke my `my.App.main(..)` method to generate something.

There is a `App.scala` file in `myproject/src/main/scala/my`, and the simplified code is like this:

```
object App {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
       val source = readContentOfFile("mysource.txt")
       val result = convert(source)
       writeToFile(result, "mytarget.txt");
   }
   // ignore some methods here
}
```

I tried to add following code into `myproject/build.sbt`:

```
lazy val generate = taskKey[Unit]("Generate my file")

generate := {
  my.App.main(Array())
}
```

But which doesn't compile since it can't find `my.App`.

Then I tried to add it to `myproject/project/build.scala`:

```
import sbt._
import my._

object HelloBuild extends Build {

  lazy val generate = taskKey[Unit]("Generate my file")

  generate := {
    App.main(Array())
  }

}
```

But it still can't be compiled, that it can't find package `my`.

How to define such a task in SBT?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In `.sbt` format, do:

```
lazy val generate = taskKey[Unit]("Generate my file")

fullRunTask(generate, Compile, "my.App")
```

This is documented at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/faq.html, “How can I create a custom run task, in addition to run?”

Another approach would be:

```
lazy val generate = taskKey[Unit]("Generate my file")

generate := (runMain in Compile).toTask(" my.App").value
```

which works fine in simple cases but isn't as customizable.

**Update:** Jacek's advice to use `resourceGenerators` or `sourceGenerators` instead is good, if it fits your use case — can't tell from your description whether it does.

Comment: In `.scala` format, you can put the `lazy val` part anywhere, and the `generate := ...` part is an ordinary setting that you can put in the same part of your `.scala` file that has the rest of your settings.

Comment: why is there a space before my ... shouldnt it be `"my.App"` instead of `" my.App"`????

Comment: I forget what the space is for. But the `toTask` examples in http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Input-Tasks.html all have it

Answer (score 10):

The other answers fit the question very well, but I think the OP might benefit from mine, too :)

The OP asked about *"I want to define a very simple task, that when I input `generate` in sbt will invoke my `my.App.main(..)` method to generate something."* that might ultimately complicate the build.

Sbt already offers a way to generate files at build time - `sourceGenerators` and `resourceGenerators` - and I can't seem to notice a need to define a separate task for this from having read the question.

In [Generating files](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html) (see [the future version of the document in the commit](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1a0ca0a7a529f84625b0f70f6a4f8404616172df/src/sphinx/Howto/generatefiles.rst)) you can read:

> sbt provides standard hooks for adding source or resource generation
>   tasks.

With the knowledge one could think of the following solution:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  my.App.main(Array()) // it's not going to work without one change, though
  Seq[File]()          // a workaround before the above change is in effect
}.taskValue
```

To make that work you should return a `Seq[File]` that contains files generated (and not the empty `Seq[File]()`).

The main change for the code to work is to move the `my.App` class to `project` folder. It then becomes a part of the build definition. It also reflects what the class does as it's really a part of the build not the artifact that's the product of it. When the same code is a part of the build *and* the artifact itself you don't keep the different concerns separate. If the `my.App` class participates in a build, it should belong to it - hence the move to the `project` folder.

The project's layout would then be as follows:

```
$ tree
.
├── build.sbt
└── project
    ├── App.scala
    └── build.properties
```

## Separation of concerns (aka *@joescii in da haus*)

There's a point in @joescii's answer (which I extend in the answer) - *"to make it a separate project that other projects can use. To do this, you will need to put your `App` object into a separate project and include it as a dependency in `project/project`"*, i.e.

Let's assume you've got a separate project `build-utils` with `App.scala` under `src/main/scala`. It's a regular sbt configuration with just the Scala code.

```
jacek:~/sandbox/so/generate-project-code
$ tree build-utils/
build-utils/
└── src
    └── main
        └── scala
            └── App.scala
```

You could test it out as a regular Scala application without messing up with sbt. No additional setup's required (and frees your mind from sbt that might be beneficial at times - less setup is always of help).

In another project - `project-code` - that uses `App.scala` that is supposed to be a base for the build, **build.sbt** is as follows:

**project-code/build.sbt**

```
lazy val generate = taskKey[Unit]("Generate my file")

generate := {
  my.App.main(Array())
}
```

Now the most important part - the wiring between projects so the `App` code is visible for the build of `project-code`:

**project-code/project/build.sbt**

```
lazy val buildUtils = RootProject(
  uri("file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/generate-project-code/build-utils")
)

lazy val plugins = project in file(".") dependsOn buildUtils
```

With the build definition(s), executing `generate` gives you the following:

```
jacek:~/sandbox/so/generate-project-code/project-code
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/generate-project-code/project-code/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/generate-project-code/build-utils/}build-utils...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/generate-project-code/project-code/project/}plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/generate-project-code/build-utils/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Set current project to project-code (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/generate-project-code/project-code/)
> generate
Hello from App.main
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed May 2, 2014 2:54:29 PM
```

I've changed the code of `App` to be:

```
> eval "cat ../build-utils/src/main/scala/App.scala"!
package my

object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello from App.main")
  }
}
```

The project structure is as follows:

```
jacek:~/sandbox/so/generate-project-code/project-code
$ tree
.
├── build.sbt
└── project
    ├── build.properties
    └── build.sbt
```

## Other changes aka goodies

I'd also propose some other changes to the code of the source generator:

- Move the code out of `main` method to a separate method that returns the files generated and have `main` call it. It'll make reusing the code in `sourceGenerators` easier (without unnecessary `Array()` to call it as well as explicitly returning the files).
- Use `filter` or `map` functions for `convert` (to add a more functional flavour).

Comment: Thank you for this solution, it's very useful if I want to create some utils for SBT. For this question, I can't choose it since I have to keep my `App.scala` in `src` directory to make others to see a standard scala project without much knowledge of sbt

Comment: Hi! How your solution will work in a multi module project? Child modules can't have their own project/build.sbt

Answer (score 5):

The solution that @SethTisue proposes will work. Another approach is to make it a separate project that other projects can use.  To do this, you will need to put your `App` object into a separate project and include it as a dependency in `project/project`, OR package it as an sbt plugin ideally with this task definition included.

For an example of how to create a lib that is packaged as a plugin, take a look at [snmp4s](https://github.com/barnesjd/snmp4s).  The `gen` directory contains the code that does some code generation (analogous to your `App` code) and the `sbt` directory contains the sbt plugin wrapper for `gen`.