# How to let sbt task to invoke project code with console arguments

Tags: scala, sbt

I dont know how to do "sbt invoke project code" and "using console arguments" together. However, I know that how I can do it separately.

Let **sbt task to invoke project code**. Basically, it can be found in 
[Defining sbt task that invokes method from project code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409993/defining-sbt-task-that-invokes-method-from-project-code)

The code sample:

```
val generateJson = inputKey[Unit]("generate json ...")

fullRunInputTask(generateJson, Test, "json.JsonGenerator")
```

Also, this is the document for the **input task argument**. http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Input-Tasks.html

```
generateJson := {
  // get the result of parsing
  val args: Seq[String] = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
  // Here, we also use the value of the `scalaVersion` setting
  println("The current Scala version is " + scalaVersion.value)
  println("The arguments to demo were:")
  args foreach println
}
```

May I know how can I combine these 2 stuff ?

Many thanks in advance