# Sbt in project plugin, how to structure them?

Tags: sbt, directory-structure, sbt-plugin

We do have a custom plugin as a single file in our `project` folder:

```
acme-project
 |- ...
 |- project
 |   |- CustomPlugin.scala

object CustomPlugin extends AutoPlugin { 
  // ...
```

That was simple and easy until that plugin started to grow...

In the first step, we added more classes/objects to the same source file. However, it continues to grow and I would like to add more structure via packages.

```
acme-project
 |- ...
 |- project
 |   |- CustomPlugin.scala
 |   |- SupportingClass.scala
 |   |- acme
 |   |   |- plugin
 |   |   |   |- PackagedClass.scala
```

My `CustomPlugin` seems to be able to use the `SupportingClass` from the folder, whenever this class declare another package. However, I cannot use the `PackagedClass` :

> [error] /~/acme-project/project/CustomPlugin.scala:1:8: not found: object acme
> [error] import mega.plugin.PackagedClass
> [error]             ^

I tried to add one `src/main/scala` folder but have the same kind of import errors.

So, I would like to know if there are ways to create large/structured plugins inside a project without making a complete one?

I would like to keep the simplicity of this format where I do not have to publish my plugin. Having it inside a dedicated module would be ok.

Thanks

Comment: For the record, it seems that Project dependency is a promising solution. I can reference a local (relative) project with `RootProject`.
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html#1d%29+Project+dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to restructure your plugin as its own sbt project, then load it as a module dependency in your project's `plugins.sbt`.

---

Move the code to its own directory.  This can be anywhere you like, e.g.:

- `acme-project/project/my-custom-plugin/`
- `acme-project/my-custom-plugin/`
- `some-other-path/my-custom-plugin/`

Write a `my-custom-plugin/build.sbt` with at least these settings:

```scala
enablePlugins(SbtPlugin)
sbtPlugin := true
scalaVersion := "2.12.16"
name := "my-custom-plugin"
```

---

Add it to your project as a module dependency in `acme-project/project/plugins.sbt`:

```scala
// For acme-project/project/my-custom-plugin/
val myCustomPlugin =
  project in file("my-custom-plugin")

// For acme-project/my-custom-plugin/
val myCustomPlugin =
  ProjectRef(file("../../my-custom-plugin"), "my-custom-plugin")

// For some-other-path/my-custom-plugin/
val myCustomPlugin =
  ProjectRef(file("/path/to/my-custom-plugin", "my-custom-plugin")

dependsOn(myCustomPlugin)
```

You only need one of those `val myCustomPlugin =` lines, depending on where you put your `my-custom-plugin/` directory.

Comment: Thanks, that was more or less what I found a few hours ago with _Project dependency_. But I was using `RootProject` instead of `ProjectRef` (See my comment on my question). 
Do you know the difference between `RootProject`, `LocalProject` and `ProjectRef`?